# GPG key generation - timeout on OSX due to lack of entropy

Tags: macos, encryption, open-source, gpg

I'm trying to generate a series of GPG keys `gpg --gen-key` but coming up with the same error that there's not enough entropy to generate a set.

```
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
jsdgpg: agent_genkey failed: Timeout
Key generation failed: Timeout
```

I can't seem to find any solution specific to OS X. Is there a way to generate more random numbers and avoid the timeout?

I'm using OS X 10.12.6 and `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.1`.

Comment: I wonder if the installation instructions for your specific GPG suite has a step to ensure the permissions to track keyboard and mouse are installer or an alternate way to generate entropy...

Comment: @bmike is there a way to check this easily. At a guess I’d say gpg will have been installed via homebrew.

Comment: The command `brew info gpg` should tell you if that's how it arrived. If so, perhaps `brew upgrade` and then `brew home gpg` to get the maintainer notes?

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you could just `rm -rf ~/.gnupg`. It works for my situation. I just force stopped the first time I ran `gpg --gen-key`, which might lead me to this `agent_genkey failed: Timeout` error.

Comment: This didn't work until I also removed the agent file `~/.gpg-agent-info` and killed the agent process `gpg-agent-info`.  Also I regenerated the key with `gpg2 --full-generate-key`

Comment: Please make sure you do not have keys there. List keys: `gpg --list-keys`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case running `killall gpg-agent` allowed the next key generation attempt to succeed.

This is preferable to deleting `~/.gnupg` and/or `~/.gpg-agent-info` if you can avoid doing so (as referenced in another answer).

(On macOS 11.2.3 Big Sur)

Comment: Just killing `gpg-agent` fixed the issue for me. Make sure there are no keys in `~/.gnupg`. To list keys `gpg --list-keys`